# How can i use this Javascript with jQuery in a INPUT TEXT?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how can i use/transform this function in order to get work into a INPUT TEXT...

Actually works if target is a DIV, but i would like use it into a INPUT TEXT...

The code i found and i want to use is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">


 $(document).ready(function (){
  textWrite("THIS'S A MESSAGE, I WOULD LIKE WRITE IT INTO A INPUT TYPE TEXT", '#write', 50);
 });

 function textList()
 {
   max = textList.arguments.length;
   for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
  this[i] = textList.arguments[i];
 }

 function textWrite(txt, selector, time)
 {
  $(selector).empty();
  var x = 0; pos = 0;
  var tl = new textList
    ( 
     txt
    );
  var l = tl[0].length;
  textInterval(selector, tl, l, x, pos, time);
 }

 function textInterval(selector, tl, l, x, pos, time)
  { 
   var interval =
   setInterval(function() {
   $(selector).html(tl[x].substring(0,pos));
   if(pos++ == l) 
    clearInterval(interval);
   }, time);
  }

</script>


<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>
<div id="write" /></div>
<input type="text" name="WriteHerePlease" id="WriteHerePlease" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thank in advance for all the help you can give me.

Comment: You surely don't want to call that as **Java**

Comment: Java ! == javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case of input field you just need to set `value` ([`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method) instead of `innerHTML` ([`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method):

```
function textWrite(txt, selector, time) {
    $(selector).val('');
    var x = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    var tl = new textList(txt);
    var l = tl[0].length;
    textInterval(selector, tl, l, x, pos, time);
}

function textInterval(selector, tl, l, x, pos, time) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $(selector).val(tl[x].substring(0, pos));
        if (pos++ == l) clearInterval(interval);
    }, time);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/epy2xrwL/

Comment: Thanks!, im sorry coz im newbie, but thanks for ur help. Just i would ask something: When the last char is wrote into the text field (so, no more chars to write) how can i set an "alert('i finished');"?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help and time, now i can continue studing about it. =)